# Adding an extra loop causes unresponsiveness

Tags: python, performance, loops, pygame

I'm making a simple game using Pygame where you have to get (by moving the cursor over them) all the circles that will appear on the screen (more will appear every second). The code is quite long so I made an example code. This code works fine, the Pygame window doesn't become unresponsive at all:

```
import pygame, random, sys

pygame.init()

window=pygame.display.set_mode((480,360))

end_program=False
while not end_program:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT  or  pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_ESCAPE]: #If the user either click the "x", or pressed the "esc" key
            end_program=True

    pass

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

However, in my game, in order to give the user the choice to play again, I need to wrap everything inside `end_program` in another loop. In the example shown, this is `break_from_second_loop`:

```
import pygame, random, sys

pygame.init()

window=pygame.display.set_mode((480,360))

end_program=False
while not end_program:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT  or  pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_ESCAPE]: #If the user either click the "x", or pressed the "esc" key
            end_program=True

    break_from_second_loop=False

    while not break_from_second_loop:
        pass

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Now if this is run, the window becomes unresponsive! Anyone know why something as simple as wrapping the code in another loop (without altering the code at all) does this?

Comment: Try creating a drastically simplified example code which exhibits this problem, this will increase your chances at a constructive reply.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph good idea, done.

Comment: It would help to explain where the code is when it becomes unresponsive. (You can do this by breaking an seeing the traceback, running in the debugger, or just adding a bunch of `print`s to trace your way through the code.)

Comment: Anyway, your simplified version makes the answer a lot more obvious: `while not break_from_second_loop: pass` can never finish, and Python can't do anything else while it's happening—including responding to events.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the game can't respond, or do anything at all, if you're not running the event loop. And in the other loop, you're not running the event loop.

This is a general problem with event-loop-based programming. You can't do anything that takes a long time, and you can't do anything that has to run across multiple events.

So, you have to break your loop apart into steps, and do just one step (or a few of them) each time through the event loop.

In this particular case, it's actually pretty simple: just change that `while` to an `if` (and move the `has_got_all_circles=False` outside the main loop), and your logic now runs exactly once each time through the event loop.

Alternatively, change it to an `if` and *also* move it inside the `for`, so now it runs exactly once per event, instead of once per event loop iteration.

A third alternative is to factor out the whole thing into a function and set it as an idle or timer function, that runs whenever the event loop is idle, or once every frame, or once every 20ms, or whatever.

It's hard to know which of the three is appropriate in your case, but the basic idea is the same in all of them, so I'll just show the second one:

```
end_program=False
break_from_second_loop=False
while not end_program:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT  or  pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_ESCAPE]: #If the user either click the "x", or pressed the "esc" key
            end_program=True
        if not break_from_second_loop:
            pass
```

---

[This blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html) explains the general problem in more detail—although most of it isn't really appropriate to this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that you're not nesting your event loop code within the while loop that does your game logic. Here's the general structure of what you want:

```
while not end_program:
    while not end_game:
        handle_events()
        do_one_frame_of_game_logic()
    offer_another_game()
```

It's possible that `offer_another_game` will also need to be run in its own loop, with its own event handling code.

Indeed, you might want to encapsulate the logic you want to use into a state machine system. You'd have states like `PlayingGame`, `GameOver`, and `DoYouWantToPlayAgain`, each of which would run for a while, then hand off to another state. Your main loop would then be something like:

```
state = StartState()
while state:
    state.handle_events()
    state.update()
    state.draw()
    state = state.next_state() # most of the time, the state will return itself
```